# How to show all the items in a MySQL database to a panel without hard coding

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing, netbeans-8

[image: panel image]

I want it to be like this. Inside the panel some details from database. Maybe a loop to do this?

Comment: This question is both unclear and too broad for Stack Overflow's format. Please read this advice on asking good questions: [[ask]], [[Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints)]. Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Answer (score 1):

You would generally display data from database tables in a `JTable`. You need to do an SQL query to get the data from the database and then you copy the data from the `ResultSet` to a `TableModel`.

Take a look at the `TableFromDatabase.java` class found in [Table From Database](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) for a generic example of this might be done.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Netbeans 7.x and above, then Right Click on the desired package (or better create one) -> New -> Other -> Swing GUI forms -> MAster Detail Sample Form.

Proceed forward, establish a database connection through the wizard, choose which entities you wish to display and let Netbeans do the rest for you.